# jQuery<number>_<number> while taking value from input text using .val()

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am getting a value from an input tag with text as type. it works normally on all devices except 5.1 (observed so far). in 5.1 sometimes gets a junk value jQuery172030903594288975_1433710908876 JQuery version is 1.7.2.
As @iblamefish requested a demo code snippet of what exactly I am trying to do,

```
$("body").on("click", ".send", function(event, ui) {

    if ($.trim($("#ConMsg").val()) != "") {
        sndMsg(id,$("#ConMsg").val(), true);
        $("#ConMsg").val("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some example code so that we can see what might be going on.

Comment: @iblamefish I have edited the question with a sample code imitating what I am trying to do. Its so simple I could not find the problem, works on all other phones except android 5.1 so far. I cannot jump platforms now from jqm to ionic or other stuffs now so please dont suggest that, I know JQM is not suitable for cordova.

Comment: its just jquery runtime object that is being sent as this. But can somebody point out where i am going wrong in the current code?